# DI Constructor Injection Neatness

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

Okay so I am looking for some specific tips about Dependency Injection and how to use it.

Basically I have a MVC website which uses Ninject (and the Ninject MVC package). So when I am creating the MVC page I use constructor injection in the controllers. This is okay but IMO a bit 'ugly', but the main thing I don't like is having to pass all of the injected repositories into the other classes, it just seems a bit OTT having to pass like 6 repositories-8 repositories into a static method or object constructor.

Not to mention that on some of my pages I am having to work on almost every repository so the controller consructor gets huge and not the most manageable.

Are there any other options that wont clutter my code up as much? I don't really want to pass them in as single 'setting' objects either as that just moves the problem to a different line of code.

I also use the same class libraries for console/desktop applications. I like the idea of using DependencyResolver.Current in the class libraries but everyone says this is an anti-pattern and constructor injection should be used.

Maybe have an MyProjectDIContext class which has a dictionary which i can populate with the injected types in the controller constructors then pass the context to all methods as needed?

I have had a look for the answer bit I can't quite seem to find something that fits well.

Comment: Can't you just register the other classes with ninject and then get the repostitories directly injected into these classes?

Comment: If I remember right without using DependencyResolver you would can't do this because "Turtles all the way down" problem.

So if the DI classes are injected into the constructor of a controller I then need to pass the resolved classes into any class that want to use it. In some cases I am doing exactly that, but it leads to a whole massive list of arguments for some more complicated processes.

A DependencyResolver avoids it but you are then tied to the resolver class which apparently isn't good.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out DI with console/desktop apps so I am not exactly sure how DI works well with them. For example I can't just go "new MyClass()" and expect it to pass in the appropriate injected classes (or can I?)?

Comment: What about the Factory extension? Then you could inject IThisControllersRepoFactory into the constructor. The interface could even reside in the controllers file making it easy to add dependencies as the occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I seem to have found a way to do this which doesn't seem as smelly!

I had thought that if you are for example using MVC you would get the Repositories in through the constructor and that was the only way to resolve the dependencies.

After doing some work to move sections of reusuable code into IoC friendly Interfaces and their implementations I noticed that when you create reference IMyInterface in a controller constructor the default constructor of the implementing class is run and you can pull other IoC classes such as resolved repositories from there.

This may be common knowledge but it does make things much much neater and solves the problem I was having.

---

Example

Controller

```
public IDefaultTemplateManager DefaultTemplateManager { get; set; }

public DefaultController(IDefaultTemplateManager defaultTemplateManager) {
    this.DefaultTemplateManager = defaultTemplateManager;
}

public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection collection) {
    DefaultTemplateManager.Process("MyKeyHere");
    View();
}
```

IDefaultTemplateManager

```
public interface IDefaultTemplateManager {
    ProcessResponse Process(string UniqueKey, DefaultTemplateManagerEditMode DatabaseName, string DefaultTemplateName);
}
```

DefaultTemplateManager

```
    public class DefaultTemplateManager : IDefaultTemplateManager {

        protected IRepository<MyEntity1> MyEntityRepo1 { get; set; }
        protected IRepository<MyEntity2> MyEntityRepo2 { get; set; }
        protected IRepository<MyEntity3> MyEntityRepo3 { get; set; }
        protected IRepository<MyEntity4> MyEntityRepo4 { get; set; }
        protected IRepository<MyEntity5> MyEntityRepo5 { get; set; }
        protected IRepository<MyEntity6> MyEntityRepo6 { get; set; }

        public DefaultTemplateManager(IRepository<MyEntity1> MyEntityRepository1, IRepository<MyEntity2> MyEntityRepository2, IRepository<MyEntity3> MyEntityRepository3, IRepository<MyEntity4> MyEntityRepository4, IRepository<MyEntity5> MyEntityRepository5, IRepository<MyEntity6> MyEntityRepository6, ) {
            this.MyEntityRepo1 = MyEntityRepository1;
            this.MyEntityRepo2 = MyEntityRepository2;
            this.MyEntityRepo3 = MyEntityRepository3;
            this.MyEntityRepo4 = MyEntityRepository4;
            this.MyEntityRepo5 = MyEntityRepository5;
            this.MyEntityRepo6 = MyEntityRepository6;
        }

        public ProcessResponse Process(string UniqueKey) {
            /* Do Work */
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the great things about Constructor Injection is that it makes design and maintainability problems more obvious. When using constructor injection, it becomes very easy to see the amount of dependencies a class has, whereas without constructor injection, a class still has the same number of dependencies, but they are tucked away.

The problem you are seeing is called [Constructor Over-injection](http://deals.manningpublications.com/DependencyInjectioninNET.pdf) and it's a design smell, because it indicates that you are violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP). The SRP guides in keeping your classes small, focussed and most of all: maintainable.

> Are there any other options that wont clutter my code up as much?

Absolutely: make smaller classes. MVC controllers typically get huge when we use it to group methods of a certain concept, such as 'customer' or 'order'. This however means that a controller is an ever growing class that has to be changed for any new feature that arrives. This is a violation of the [Open/closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) that tells we should strive to have a system where we can plugin new features without having to touch existing classes.

The solution therefore is not to revert to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) or Property Injection, but to create smaller classes that do one particular thing. Constructor Injection should be your primary way of applying Dependency Injection, even in class libraries.

Comment: While I do know what you mean, and I have heard it before. I am not quite sure how I would go about doing it in practice lol :) I mean in some places in my code I use 'XManager' type of classes which handle Searches, File Generation, etc. In the case of a create wizard I have is injecting 8 repositories into the constructor, on this page the final action is 336 lines long. So your suggestion would be to split this into little chunks and only pass the repository needed to save that data? Actually after looking at that code it isn't the best example as it is something I should have done anyway!

Comment: 336 lines long? Wow! That is absolutely bad for maintainability. Without seeing the exact code, it's really hard to explain how this should be improved. The first link I gave might give some ideas though. It talks about [Aggregate Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) (although named differently). This is certainly something you should try.

Comment: Here is one of my file generation classes "MainJSON tmpMain = new MainJSON(tmpClientKey, clientcol, sitecol, configcol, configtemplatecol, configitemdefcol, generatedfilecol);". So i have a record key, 5 repositories to take data from and 1 repository to write to. The Main.json file needs all this data to create the file so would this actually be considered smell or should I load all of the data out into their objects then pass them in? I like it 'neat' in its own little box, want a Main.json file then you just create that class then run ProcessToDatabase method seems more simple.

Comment: Yes @Steven I do understand that 336 lines is too long ... it's why i said it wasn't the best example because it isn't how I would program it now and it will probably be refactored soon :)

Comment: It seems like your controller is just shuffling repositories. You could have Ninject create a MainJSONFactory for you, resolving the dependencies at creation of MainJSON (instead of doing it yourself, with new).

Comment: @Andreas can you give an example in a new answer please? I am not sure how I would go about achieving this in Ninject. Specifically regarding how ninject will inject into the factory.

Comment: There is a well known pattern/name for an aggregation of repositories: it is called a unit of work. Just look at what EF does with its `DbContext`. It gives you access to repositories by calling `context.Customers` or `context.Orders`.

Comment: @Steven I kind of use something like this except I use text keys and a dictionary to store it. I did see something mention that this was bad practice though :/

Comment: @Dwiea: It depends. Unit of work is a very common pattern, but that doesn't mean that it's okay to group all dependencies whitout abstracting away their behavior. The goal is to lower the system's complexity and make it more maintainable. This is the question you should keep asking yourself: how does this make my class simpler and more maintainble?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your controller is shuffling repositories to other classes. Let Ninject supply those classes to you instead:

```
public class Controller
{
    public Controller(IDependencyFactory dependency) { }
}

public interface IDependencyFactory
{
    IDependency CreateDependency();
}

public interface IDependency
{
}

public class Dependency : IDependency
{
    public Dependency() { }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var standardKernel = new StandardKernel();
        standardKernel.Bind<IDependencyFactory>().ToFactory();
        standardKernel.Bind<IDependency>().To<Dependency>();
    }
}
```

You don't have to write an implementation of `IDependencyFactory`, that is handled by the factory extension. Your `Dependency`-class will get it's dependencies injected by Ninject.

Comment: What problem does this solve? By doing this you double the amount of dependencies the class has and with that you increase the class's complexity.

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean. If you switch your injection of 8 repositories to e.g. one RepositoryFactory instead, how are your dependencies doubled? You could even have a generic RepositoryFactory for all repositories. It's like a restricted service locator, but you are not exposing all services to your code.

Comment: A class’s dependencies are not only the classes you inject, but you will have to count everything the class depends on. In the case of a factory, the abstraction returned by the factory is a dependency as well. So for each factory, you get a second dependency. You will immediately notice this added complexity when you start unit testing, because you will have to test both the interaction with the factory and the abstraction exposed by the factory. So in general, the use of factories increases the complexity of a class instead of decreasing it.

Comment: An article that goes into more details is this one: [Abstract Factories are a Code Smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100).